# Conflicting method/name for an OData Endpoint

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, odata

My `program.cs` looks like below:

```
.
.

builder.Services.AddControllers()
.AddOData(options =>
{
    options.Select().Count().AddRouteComponents(WeatherEDM.GetEdmModel());
});
.
.
.
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

`WeatherEDM`:

```
public class WeatherEDM
    {
        public static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
        {
            var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.Namespace = "Weather NS";
            builder.ContainerName = "Weather Container";

            builder.EntitySet<WeatherForecast>("WeatherForecast");

            return builder.GetEdmModel();
        }
```

`WeatherForecastController.cs`:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ODataController
     .
     .
     .
     [HttpGet]
     [EnableQuery]
     public IQueryable<WeatherForecast> Get()
     {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
          Id = index,
          Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
          TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
          Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        }).AsQueryable();
      }
```

When I am trying to run the API, the Swagger is throwing an error like this:

`An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGeneratorException: Conflicting method/path combination "GET WeatherForecast" for actions - Weather.Controllers.WeatherForecastController.Get (Weather),Weather.Controllers.WeatherForecastController.Get (Weather). Actions require a unique method/path combination for Swagger/OpenAPI 3.0. Use ConflictingActionsResolver as a workaround`

Although when I remove `Route[..]` attribute from the controller, the app loads without errors.

Can someone please tell what is going wrong here on adding `Route[..]` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Mrityu

This error makes sense to me since you have 'builder.EntitySet("WeatherForecast");' in your model builder.

OData library will try to build the endpoint for all actions within 'WeatherForecastController', (be noted, the controller convention is 'entitysetname' + Controller.

'public IQueryable Get() ' methods follow up query entity set convention. So, OData builds `HttpGet /WeatherForecastController' endpoint.

Meanwhile, you have [Route("[controller]")] on your controller, it goes to normal asp.net core attribute routing, that is aps.net core builds the same endpoint for "Get()" method.

So, you got the "conflicting method". Remove "Route[..]" should work.
If you want to get odata and non-odata responses both from one controller/action, you should make the route template distinguish. One option is add a prefix when calling 'AddRouteComponent'. Hope it can help.